# Apache Commons HttpClient for HTTPS call

Tags: java, security, https

Does HttpClient uses cacerts that is available in every JRE? do i need to configure the HttpClient with SSL to invoke a HTTPS endpoint.

The endpoint uses GeoTrust which is a trusted authority by cacerts withing JRE. Does HttpClient handle the security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Commons HttpClient API that allows a developer custom control over SSL parameters. You don't need to configure Commons HttpClient specifically; HttpClient will delegate SSL verification and so forth to whatever Java-standard SSL sockets use. That, in turn, will end up in your JRE's `cacerts` file being inquired for CA validation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, according to the [website](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html). If you have [JSSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) installed and all JDKs after 1.4 come with it out of the box, SSL works with the httpclient library (any version) just as you would with any other request.